# Firebase 4.0 DatabaseReference Error

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

After migrating to Firebase 4.0 , I have this REALLY annoying issue with the Reference to the DB.*

> "Cannot convert return expression of type 'DatabaseReference' to
>   return type 'DatabaseReference'

Very frustating , I try to make a switch on a *enum*, to set multiple *ref*.

Even when I try to follow the new Docs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtTQ2.png)

Comment: `FireBase 4.0` has few changes. Check new `FireBase 4.0` doc.

Comment: Any reasons why you don't just define it as a constant? let ref = Database.database().reference()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is getting confused with the Firebase class `DatabaseReference` and your enum of the same name `DatabaseReference`. Try using a different name for your enum.

Answer (score 0):

```
pod 'Firebase', '<4'
pod 'Firebase/Database', '<4'
pod 'Firebase/Auth', '<4'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @erdos's solution, if you want to keep you enum name then reference the module FirebaseDatabase:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DatabaseReference
```